# Como passar valor alterado dinamicamente para função, em AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5

Os campos itemCodigo, itemDescricao, itemPreco e itemQuantidade são preenchidos dinamicamente (em tempo de execução, sem *refresh*) a partir de uma consulta realizada no banco de dados. Contudo esses valores, ao serem passados como parâmetro para a função addItem(), retornam `undefined`, ou seja, ao clicar no botão "Inserir", os campos que deveriam ser "clonados" para a tabela [Código | Descrição | Preço | Quantidade] ficam em branco.

Ilustração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controlador">
       <input type="text" name="busca" placeholder="Pesquisar produto"/>
       <br /><br />
       <input type="button" value="Inserir" id="inserir-item"  ng-click="addItem(itemCodigo, itemDescricao, itemPreco, itemQuantidade)"/>
       <br /><br />
       <input type="text" id="codigo" readonly ng-model="itemCodigo">
       <input type="text" id="descricao" readonly ng-model="itemDescricao">
       <input type="text" id="preco" readonly ng-model="itemDescricao">
       <br /><br />

<td>{{item.codigo}}</td>
<td>{{item.descricao}}</td>
<td>{{item.preco}}</td>
<td>{{item.quantidade}}</td>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("controlador", function($scope){
    $scope.addItem = function (itemCodigo, itemDescricao, itemPreco, itemQuantidade) {
              $scope.items.push({
                  codigo: itemCodigo,
                  descricao: itemDescricao,
                  preco: itemPreco,
                  quantidade, itemQuantidade
        });
    };
})
```

Obs.: itemQuantidade, está definido em outro input dentro do código.

Comment: cadê o seu array $scope.items????

Comment: $scope.items = [];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem que criar no seu `$scope` o `array` de `items` e para inicializar pode ser utilizado de duas formas, uma dentro do próprio `controller` e outra pelo [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) atribuindo o valor em uma expressão simples.

1) Atribuindo os valores por [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("controlador", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.addItem = function(itemCodigo, itemDescricao) {
      $scope.items.push({
        codigo: itemCodigo,
        descricao: itemDescricao
      });
      console.log($scope.items);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controlador">
  <input type="text" name="busca" placeholder="Pesquisar produto" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Inserir" id="inserir-item" ng-click="addItem(itemCodigo, itemDescricao)" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="codigo" name="ttl" ng-init="itemCodigo=1" ng-model="itemCodigo">
  <input type="text" id="descricao" name="ttl" ng-init="itemDescricao = 'ttl'" ng-model="itemDescricao">
  <br />
  <br />
  <td>{{item.codigo}}</td>
  <td>{{item.descricao}}</td>
</div>
```

---

2) Atribuindo os valores no próprio `controller`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("controlador", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.itemCodigo = 1;
    $scope.itemDescricao = "desc";
    $scope.addItem = function(itemCodigo, itemDescricao) {
      $scope.items.push({
        codigo: itemCodigo,
        descricao: itemDescricao
      });
      console.log($scope.items);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controlador">
  <input type="text" name="busca" placeholder="Pesquisar produto" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Inserir" id="inserir-item" ng-click="addItem(itemCodigo, itemDescricao)" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="codigo" name="ttl" ng-model="itemCodigo">
  <input type="text" id="descricao" name="ttl" ng-model="itemDescricao">
  <br />
  <br />
  <td>{{item.codigo}}</td>
  <td>{{item.descricao}}</td>
</div>
```

<sub>**Particularmente**, prefiro a segunda opção, por ser mais fácil a identificação das variáveis.</sub>

***Referencia:*** [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

### @@Edit

Eu entendi que precisa fazer uma listagem com os elementos escolhidos na consulta, vou colocar um exemplo minimo para que encaixa da melhor maneira possível.

*Exemplo Minimo*

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("controlador", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.itemCodigo = 1;
    $scope.itemDescricao = "desc";
    $scope.addItem = function(s) {
      $scope.items.push({
        codigo: s.codigo,
        descricao: s.descricao,
        preco: s.preco,
        quantidade: s.quantidade
      });
      s.codigo = 0;
      s.descricao = '';
      s.preco = 0,00;
      s.quantidade = 0;
      $("#c").focus();
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controlador">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%">Código</td>
      <td width="25%">Descrição</td>
      <td width="25%">Preço</td>
      <td width="25%">Quantidade</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="s.codigo" id="c" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="s.descricao" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="s.preco" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="s.quantidade" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <button style="width: 250px" ng-click="addItem(s);">
          Inserir
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="25%">Código</td>
        <td width="25%">Descrição</td>
        <td width="25%">Preço</td>
        <td width="25%">Quantidade</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="items.length>0">
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="item.codigo" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="item.descricao" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="item.preco" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="item.quantidade" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

A adequação é feita no seu código, porque, não tem aquela lista para simular, isso é o mais próximo, qualquer dúvida pergunte.

Comment: Boa noite Virgilio Novic, agradeço desde já a disposição, contudo ainda não é o que preciso. Olhe estas imagens para ver se compreende melhor: [1] prnt.sc/dlz9dq → [2] prnt.sc/dlz9tq, ou seja, os campos que são preenchidos automaticamente a partir da busca, ao clicar no botão "Inserir", deverão ser "clonados" para a tabela abaixo [Código | Descrição | Preço | Quantidade].

Comment: @luccasrodrigo não ficou muito claro na sua pergunta, mas, você precisa gerar uma lista de valores a partir da inserção de um valor que vem do banco? Talvez precisa fazer uma edição na sua pergunta relatando essas duas imagens ... fico no aguardo.

Comment: Boa tarde @virgilionovic, edições realizadas.

Comment: @luccasrodrigo eu fiz um exemplo minimo, por não ter a lista que tem no seu código, mas, isso vai te ajudar a solucionar a maior parte do seu problema ou talvez tudo com esse empurrão, espero que tenha ajudado, pois, a minha ideia sempre é ajudar ...

Comment: Boa tarde novamente @virgilionovic, testei esse "Exemplo Mínimo" e não funcionou. Tentei modificar à minha realidade e também não deu certo. Pesquisei no http://stackoverflow.com/ e encontrei uma solução quase próxima ao que preciso, contudo não consegui fazer o exemplo funcionar com button. Outro detalhe, é que os campos, que deveriam ser preenchidos manualmente, são preenchidos através de uma função, e quando clico em inserir ele não reconhece o valor do input.

Comment: Publicação mencionada [Usuário: @shashankagrawal]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34195086/angularjs-copy-the-value-of-one-input-box-to-another-input-box-only-if-checkbox

Comment: O problema @luccasrodrigo não a minha solução, é como está a sua, porque essa resposta funciona normalmente só precisa ser adaptado ao seu cenário que não é **claro** para uma resposta objetiva! Peço desculpas por algo. Funcionamento do exemplo minimo só para deixar claro, é preencher manualmente os campos e clicar no botão, será criado uma lista de itens como você quer!

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção é criar essas variáveis no controller, na função que preenche elas e não passar por argumento:

**HTML**

```
 <input type="button" value="Inserir" id="inserir-item"  ng-click="addItem()"/>
```

**Angular controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

$scope.itemCodigo = "algum_valor";
$scope.itemDescricao = "outro_valor";
$scope.items = [];

app.controller("controlador", function($scope){
    $scope.addItem = function () {
              $scope.items.push({
                  codigo: $scope.itemCodigo,
                  descricao: $scope.itemDescricao
        });
    };
})
```

Comment: Boa noite Lucas Costa, agradeço também a disposição em ajudar, contudo seguindo o mesmo raciocínio que passei para o Virgilio, olhe estas imagens para ver se compreende melhor: [1] prnt.sc/dlz9dq → [2] prnt.sc/dlz9tq, ou seja, os campos que são preenchidos automaticamente a partir da busca, ao clicar no botão "Inserir", deverão ser "clonados" para a tabela abaixo [Código | Descrição | Preço | Quantidade].

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde @virgilionovic, consegui uma solução "improvisada", pegando os valores da seguinte forma:

```
$scope.items.push({
            codigo: $("input[name='codigo']").val(),
            descricao: $("input[name='descricao']").val(),
            preco: $("input[name='preco']").val(),
            quantidade: s.quantidade,
            soma: sum++
 });
```

Comment: Isso devido ao problema de não conseguir copiar e exibir (na cesta de itens) os valores que eram armazenados dinamicamente no input.

Comment: @lucasrodrigo o mais engraçado que o `s.quantidade` você consegiu?