# Como verificar, para cada item inserido no $scope.items[], se os campos foram preenchidos

Tags: html, angularjs

Como verificar, para cada item inserido no $scope.items[], se **Telefone** e **CPF** foram preenchidos?

**Cenário pretendido:**

→ O usuário deverá inserir no mínimo 1 item, caso negativo, ao clicar em "Enviar" é exibo um "alert"[JÁ IMPLEMENTADO]

→ Ao clicar em "Enviar" e o usuário não preencheu os campos **Telefone** e **CPF**, para cada item inserido, deverá ser exibido um "alert". [PROBLEMA]

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('controlador', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.user = {};
    $scope.produtoTrib = {};
 $scope.items = [];
 var sum = 1;
 
 $scope.addItem = function (user){
   $scope.items.push({
    nome: $("input[name='nome']").val(),
    email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
    soma: sum++
   });
    user.nome = '';
    user.email = ''; 
 };
      
     
    $scope.addTributos = function (produto){
        $scope.produtoTrib = produto;
 };
    
   $scope.submitForm = function() {
       if(sum <= 1){
         alert("Insira no mínimo 1 (um) item.");  
       }
   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controlador">

<form ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <label>Nome: </label><input type="text" name="nome" ng-model="user.nome" style="width:100px">
    <label>E-mail: </label><input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user.email" style="width:100px">
    
    <input type="text" hidden name="email" ng-model="user.telefone">
    <input type="text" hidden name="email" ng-model="user.cpf">
    
    <input type="button" value="Adicionar" ng-click="addItem(user)" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
<br />

<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
ID: {{item.soma}}<br />
Nome: {{item.nome}}<br />
E-mail: {{item.email}}<br /><br />
<!-- {{item.telefone}} - {{item.cpf}} -->
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="addTributos(item)">Tributos</button>
<hr />
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Tributos</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label>Telefone: </label><input type="text" name="telefone" ng-model="produtoTrib.telefone">
        <label>CPF: </label><input type="text" name="cpf" ng-model="produtoTrib.cpf">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Atualizar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: é uma coisa que ando vendo no seus códigos em angular, se ta misturando jQuery com Angular sem necessidade, deve rever isso para os seus futuros códigos. um conselho...

Comment: Sim, tenho ciência. Obrigado pelo conselho, estou procurando rever isso, contudo esta linha `nome: $("input[name='nome']").val()`, em outro código (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172553/31236) não funcionou `nome: $scope.nome` ou `nome: user.nome`. @VirgilioNovic, até mencionei você na resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173311/31236

Comment: talvez por não conseguir você achou uma forma rapida de solucionar o problema, acredito que não estava pertencente ao controller e a a aplicação, é alguma coisa... mas, sem ver fica complicado. Aquela tela eu lembro bem, fiz o máximo para ajudar, mas, sem ver o código aonde está rodando a gente acaba sem saber o que está programado, é bem complicado mesmo e eu entendo você ...!!!

Comment: Agradeço pela disposição! Estarei revendo o que ocorreu, realmente foi uma "gambiarra" pela necessidade rápida que tinha de resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrescente uma função para validar os campos antes de executar o `push`.

Ex.:

```
var validar = function() {

    if(!$scope.myForm.nome.$valid) {
        alert('Digite o nome!');
        return false;   
    };

    if(!$scope.myForm.email.$valid) {
        alert('Digite o email!');
        return false;   
    };
    return true;
}

$scope.addItem = function (user){
    if(validar()){
        $scope.items.push({
            nome: $("input[name='nome']").val(),
            email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
            soma: sum++
        });
      user.nome = '';
      user.email = '';
    }               
};
```

Atribuir um nome para o elemento `form` irá facilitar na utilização da validação do próprio AngularJS, neste exemplo utilizei o **myForm** e inclui o `novalidate` para não executar a validação do HTML5.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
```

A validação do AngularJS utiliza o atributo `required` do HTML5 para especificar que o campo deve ser preenchido:

Antes:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" ng-model="user.nome" style="width:100px">
<input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user.email" style="width:100px">
```

Depois:

```
<input type="text" required name="nome" ng-model="user.nome" style="width:100px">
<input type="text" required name="email" ng-model="user.email" style="width:100px">
```

Utilize o próprio elemento `input[type=hidden]` e troque o nome dos elementos `input[name=email]` a fim de evitar conflitos durante a validação:

Antes:

```
<input type="text" hidden name="email" ng-model="user.telefone">
<input type="text" hidden name="email" ng-model="user.cpf">
```

Depois:

```
<input type="text" hidden  name="telefone" ng-model="user.telefone">
<input type="text"  hidden name="cpf" ng-model="user.cpf">
```

E para verificar se algum item de `$scope.items` está com o CPF ou Telefone faltando, executa o `for` e percorre os itens verificando:

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
   if(sum <= 1){
     alert("Insira no mínimo 1 (um) item.");
     return false;  
   }
   for (var i = $scope.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     var item = $scope.items[i];
     if(!$scope.items[i].cpf) {
      alert('Por gentileza, preencha o CPF de '+item.nome);
      return false;
     }         
     if(!$scope.items[i].telefone) {
      alert('Por gentileza, preencha o telefone de '+item.nome);
      return false;
     }
   }
```

}

Resultado:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('controlador', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.user = {};
    $scope.produtoTrib = {};
 $scope.items = [];
 var sum = 1;
 
 var validar = function() {

  if(!$scope.myForm.nome.$valid) {
            alert('Digite o nome!');
            return false; 
        };

        if(!$scope.myForm.email.$valid) {
            alert('Digite o email!');
            return false; 
        };
     return true;
    }

 $scope.addItem = function (user){
  if(validar()){
   $scope.items.push({
    nome: $("input[name='nome']").val(),
    email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
    soma: sum++
   });
    user.nome = '';
    user.email = '';
  }
    
 };
      
      
    $scope.addTributos = function (produto){
        $scope.produtoTrib = produto;
 };
    
   $scope.submitForm = function() {
   if(sum <= 1){
     alert("Insira no mínimo 1 (um) item.");
     return false;  
   }
   for (var i = $scope.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     var item = $scope.items[i];
     if(!$scope.items[i].cpf) {
      alert('Por gentileza, preencha o CPF de '+item.nome);
      return false;
     }         
     if(!$scope.items[i].telefone) {
      alert('Por gentileza, preencha o telefone de '+item.nome);
      return false;
     }
   }
   }
   
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controlador">

<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
    <label>Nome: </label><input type="text" required name="nome" ng-model="user.nome" style="width:100px">
    <label>E-mail: </label><input type="text" required name="email" ng-model="user.email" style="width:100px">
    
    <input type="hidden" name="telefone" ng-model="user.telefone">
    <input type="hidden" name="cpf" ng-model="user.cpf">
    
    <input type="button" value="Adicionar" ng-click="addItem(user)" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
<br />

<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
ID: {{item.soma}}<br />
Nome: {{item.nome}}<br />
E-mail: {{item.email}}<br /><br />
<!-- {{item.telefone}} - {{item.cpf}} -->
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="addTributos(item)">Tributos</button>
<hr />
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Tributos</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label>Telefone: </label><input type="text" name="telefone" ng-model="produtoTrib.telefone">
        <label>CPF: </label><input type="text" name="cpf" ng-model="produtoTrib.cpf">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Atualizar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Carlos, exatamente o que precisava! A recompensa estará liberada em 4 horas. @CarlosFernandes

Answer (score 1):

Você já está vinculando os dois *inputs* ao modelo:

```
<label>Nome: </label><input type="text" ng-model="user.nome">
<label>E-mail: </label><input type="text" ng-model="user.email">
```

Assim sendo, o trecho abaixo é desnecessário:

```
{nome: $("input[name='nome']").val()}
```

Você pode simplesmente mencionar o modelo no escopo:

```
{nome: $scope.user.nome}
```

Assim sendo, teste o modelo diretamente:

```
var temNome = !!$scope.user.nome;
```

Comment: Olá @OnoSendai, poderia ver a edição que realizei? [Cenário pretendido]